# Guardian 1.0 failing auth when using key option

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using the library `Guardian` 1.0 with an auth pipeline defined like this:

```
defmodule DokkitoWeb.Plug.GuardianPipeline do
  use Guardian.Plug.Pipeline, otp_app: :dokkito,
                          module: DokkitoWeb.Guardian,
                          error_handler: DokkitoWeb.Plug.AuthErrorHandler,
                          key: :user

  plug Guardian.Plug.VerifySession
  plug Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated
  plug Guardian.Plug.LoadResource
end
```

My sign in code in the controller is doing:

```
DokkitoWeb.Guardian.Plug.sign_in(conn, user, key: :user)
```

When going through the pipeline I'm getting

```
{
  "message": "unauthenticated"
}
```

If I remove `key: :user` in both `sign_in` call and the pipeline it's authenticating fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Basically I needed to write :
`conn = Guardian.Plug.sign_in(conn, user, %{}, key: :user)`
otherwise the key was added to the claims instead of the options. My god that was complicated to debug...